# How to stop EJB Schedulers to become timeout for a certain timeperiod in Websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere-8, ejbscheduler

I have an EJB scheduler, This scheduler calls a procedure. The procedure takes 25 minutes to fetch the data.

Now, my EJB scheduler gets timed out before the procedure could get complete.

Is there any way I can configure my EJB schedulers to do not get timed out until the process gets complete or for certain period?

I am using EJB schedulers in WAS 85

Comment: What do you mean by "gets timed out"?  What message/error are you getting in the log, or what behavior are you observing?  Transaction timeout?  Hung thread detection?

Comment: Means, scheduler throws transaction timed out exception before the procedure gets complete its process.